# Copying OS to disk image

Tags: assembly, kernel, bootloader, hex-editors

Recently I have just built a version of my OS, and I am trying to copy it to a disk image. My Windows 8.1 install does not come with the debug command, so I am using a hex editor (HxD) to copy the bootloader to the boot sector. The way I am doing it is as follows:

1. Create a disk image with ImDisk Virtual Disk
2. Open disk image and bootloader binary file in HxD
3. Replace default hex code with the hex's from the binary file
4. Remove the first three hex's that show up in Sector 1 (so that its blank), and save.
5. Mount the floppy image and drag the kernel (KERNEL.SYS) onto the floppy drive

Yet when I dismount the floppy drive, open VirtualBox, and select the floppy image for the floppy drive, I am greeted with this screen when I start it:

[image]

In case this is due to an error in which I have coded the kernel, and not a mistake I have made while copying with the hex editor, here are the pastebin links:

Kernel.asm

http://pastebin.com/0A6fAqs3

Bootloader.asm

http://pastebin.com/hQX3VDsv

Comment: what is your question? you `retf` from bootloader to 0x0050:0, but in kenel you init `ds/es` to 0x07c0. then you set cursor, but don't give its position in `dx`. then you... oO write 2000 spaces to clear the screen? this is not how you clear the screen :) either set video mode or write spaces directly to video memory (the latter is faster). and what is point 4 `Remove the last three hex's that show up in Sector 1`? you remove bytes from offset 509-511? why?

Comment: @AlexanderZhak I fixed the mistake I made in the post. After generating the disk image, three bytes were in Sector 1. I cleared those out as it didn't seem like they had to be there, was that wrong?

Comment: Sector 1 - the second (physical)? You just ruin your fat

Comment: @AlexanderZhak Okay, thanks for the tip. After replacing Sector 0 with the boot loader code, it will leave the three bytes remaining in Sector 1.

Comment: Unlike everything else in the known universe, sector numbers start with 1.